# how to use buttons to call functions that draw in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, function, canvas

For this project, we're working with canvas. I need to create some buttons, and when you click on the buttons, the corresponding function should be called. These functions will then draw something in the canvas. However, my code isn't working. The buttons and the canvas themselves appear, but nothing draws when you click on the buttons. Are there any errors?

```
<script>
    function drawCircle(){
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    function drawLine(){
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.moveTo(0,0);
        ctx.lineTo(200,100);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    function drawRectangle(){
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
    }       
    function drawImage(){
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        var img = document.getElementById("scream");
        ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
    }   
    function drawText(){
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.font = "30px Arial";
        ctx.fillText("Hello World",10,50);
    }

</script>
</head>


<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>

<input type="button" onclick="drawCircle();" value="Draw Circle">
<input type="button" onclick="drawLine();" value="Draw Line">
<input type="button" onclick="drawRectangle();" value="Draw Rectangle">
<input type="button" onclick="drawImage();" value="Draw Line">
<input type="button" onclick="drawText();" value="Text">
<input type="button" onclick="drawGradient();" value="Gradient">
<input type="button" onclick="scale();" value="Scale">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems to work fine for me (in Chrome and IE at least).  How are you running it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in CodePen and the buttons for which you've implemented the function work just fine. Does your console show any errors?